# Will nanobots keep my pilot alive if I use the self destruct button?

Tags: into-the-breach

If I have the Nano Mech in my squad (or find/buy the nanobot system) and I come into possession of a Self Destruct Button, will the nanobots heal damage for every enemy I kill when I use it, keeping my mech (and pilot) alive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, healing from an attack that brings your mech's health to 0 will save both the mech and the pilot.

Comment: I've tried it with the normal Hazardous Mech attacks, but haven't tried it with the button yet. I assumed the answer would be "Yes, they live", but I assumed Prospero would count for the flight achievement too, and he doesn't. Have you managed to try it yet?

Comment: I've tried it myself now, and this answer is right. I've attached a gif demonstrating it.

Comment: Well I tried to add a gif demonstrating it, but the edit was rejected. It does work though.

Comment: @playerone Can you link it in a comment?

Comment: @Studoku Sure, it's here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMH1x.gif

Comment: The first kill was my control to make sure the nanobots were working